# How to display the filegroup name used in textimage_on option?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table defined like this

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    [int] INT
    ,[varchar] VARCHAR(max)
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [A_varchar_FG]
```

I tried the following script but am only able to see the `[PRIMARY]` filegroup.

```
SELECT t.name AS tablename
    ,fg.name AS filegroup
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
JOIN sys.filegroups fg ON i.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in `sys.tables.lob_data_space_id`, eg:

```
SELECT 
     t.name AS tablename
    ,fg.name AS filegroup
    ,fg_lob.name as lob_filegroup 
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
JOIN sys.filegroups fg ON i.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id
LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups fg_lob on t.lob_data_space_id = fg_lob.data_space_id
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this query to display the table's filegroups and size:

```
SELECT  SCHEMA_NAME(T.SCHEMA_ID)+'.'+T.NAME                 AS  TABLE_NAME,
        MIN(T.CREATE_DATE)                                  AS  CREATE_DATE,
        DS.NAME                                             AS  FILEGRP,
        CAST(SUM(U.TOTAL_PAGES) * 8 AS FLOAT) / 1024        AS  SIZE_MB,
        CAST(SUM(U.TOTAL_PAGES) * 8 AS FLOAT) / 1024 / 1024 AS  SIZE_GB,
        SCHEMA_NAME(T.SCHEMA_ID)                            AS  SCHEMA_NAME
FROM    SYS.TABLES AS T ( NOLOCK )
INNER JOIN SYS.PARTITIONS AS P ( NOLOCK ) ON T.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN SYS.ALLOCATION_UNITS AS U ( NOLOCK ) ON P.PARTITION_ID = U.CONTAINER_ID
INNER JOIN SYS.DATA_SPACES AS DS ( NOLOCK ) ON U.DATA_SPACE_ID = DS.DATA_SPACE_ID
WHERE   T.name = 'A'
GROUP BY T.NAME,
        DS.NAME,
        T.SCHEMA_ID
ORDER BY SIZE_MB DESC
```